# Compress only some files type

Tags: linux, shell

I start on shell and i don't know how to compress a folder including just the .jpg and .jpeg files.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?  Do you mean to just "include" .jpg files in the archive without compression operations performed on those files, while compressing all other files?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tar cvf jpeg.tar $(find /path/to/folder -iregex ".*\.jpe?g")
$ find /path/to/folder -type f -iregex ".*\.jpe?g" | xargs tar cvf jpg.tar
```

Comment: I would prefer the latter version as the first one might fail in case of many files to compress. This is avoided by the second variant which uses xargs to overcome that problem.  (@quanta: a little bit of explanation would  be helpful in a case like that).

Answer (score 1):

Go to folder

```
zip archive *.jpg *.jpeg
```

else, from anywhere

```
zip archive /path/to/folder/*.jpg /path/to/folder/*.jpeg
```

*archive* is the output file.